# How do I calculate cost savings and profits in this example?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

[image]

How are `profits` and `cost savings` calculated in this table?

Is there enough given data to calculate these two?

Here is what I do know:

ROI = (cum profits - cum cost)/cum cost
Sales = (Market Size * Market Share)
Change in profits = (new profit - old profit + cost savings)
Cum. Change in profits = addition of profits from each year
Market share = given
Cum. Cost = given

(Next, need to work out an alternate version when the market size grows only $20M/year from 2004 - some linear interpolation required.)

I am not sure how these 2 values are calculated, any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Thank You.

**EDIT:**
Looks like difference of new and old profit is same to difference between cost savings and change in profits...

Comment: It looks to me like they are givens, not calculated from other data in the table.

Comment: interesting, both givens and independent of each other?

Comment: I can't see how to calculate them from the other data.  I agree with your edit, but that restates the equation you gave for change in profits.  So I think these two are used just as you say.

Comment: @Ross: Thank you, would this make to interpolate these two values for the new figure?